# RSpec stub a method that's used inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, stub, stubbing

I'm trying to stub a method that's called inside a controller, but it only gets stubbed within the test and not when it's called in the controller.

Target method:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.fetch_boolean(arg)
    MyModel.find_by({ name: arg })
    MyModel.value
  end
end
```

Target controller:

```
# controller
class OtherModelController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  if MyModel.fetch_boolean('123')
    # do something
  end

  # ...
end
```

RSpec test:

```
describe 'test' do
  before(:each) do
    allow(MyModel).to receive(:fetch_boolean).with('123').and_return(true)
  end

  it 'should do something' do
    get :show
    expect(response).to eq('hello')
  end
end
```

I called `debugger` within the RSpec test and called `MyModel.fetch_boolean` and got `true`. However, when I called it inside the controller, I got `false` (which is the stored value).

How do I make sure that the method inside the controller also gets stubbed?

RSpec version 3.7

Update:

Other stubbing syntaxes I've tried

```
allow(MyModel).to receive(:fetch_boolean).with('123') { true }
# same outcome

allow_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:fetch_boolean).with('123') { true }
# error: MyModel does not implement #fetch_boolean

controller.stub(MyModel.fetch_boolean).with('123') { true }
# error: Wrong number of arguments. Expected 1, got 0

controller.stub(MyModel.fetch_boolean('123')) { true }
# error: true is not a symbol nor a string
```

Comment: Your stubbing code is correct, so something else is the problem. Can you put breakpoints where you stub the method and inside the method - perhaps it's getting  called before it's getting stubbed?

Comment: Also - it's possible to redefine a class or method if you're doing very funky/unusual things that would cause the stub to go away, but that would be pretty uncommon.

Comment: @melcher thank you, I put a `debugger` in the controller and also in `before(:each)`, I found that the controller's debugger was executed before the one in the `before(:each)`, could that play a part in all this?

Comment: @melcher someone advised redefining that class, and it works. However, I need it to be `true` for some tests and `false` for other tests. Redefining it in the spec will cause it to always return `true` for that test suite.

Comment: what happen if you remove the part `.with('123')`, Or you could add one more expect `expect(MyModel).to have_received(:fetch_boolean).with('123')` to make sure that the stub method is called (with `123`).

Comment: I would extract this out into a minimal, verifyable example and see if you can actually reproduce the behavior if you break it down to the bare minimum. As @melcher pointed out the problem is not how you're stubbing it or any of the code actually presented in the answer. You should also be aware that the using controller specs is greatly discouraged and that `ActionController::TestCase` which it builds on is depreachiated and is slated to be removed from Rails. Its not a future proof method (or a good method) and has no place outside of legacy code. Use request specs instead.